Expectation of $\log\Gamma(x)$ where $x$ is Log-Normal
I'm trying to set up a variational inference on a gamma-gamma model:
$$f(\alpha, Y) =\prod_{i=1}^n\text{Gamma}(y_i\mid\alpha,1)\times\text{Gamma}(\alpha\mid a, b)$$
The ELBO, or evidenciary lower bound, is the value we try to maximize in variational inference (as the ELBO + KL divergence adds up to a fixed quantity, the 'evidence'.  so maximizing the ELBO is equivalent to minimizing KL Divergence.  The ELBO is formed as:
$$
\text{ELBO} = \text{E}_q\left[\log f(\alpha, Y) - \log q(\alpha)\right]
$$
Then by differentiating with respect to the parameters of $q$, we find the gradient, and can optimize it.  Anyways,
letting $q(\alpha) = \text{LogNormal}(\alpha\mid\mu,\sigma)$, all the terms in the ELBO have relatively simple, closed form expectations.. except: $n\log\Gamma(\alpha)$.
Is there any way to make this integral work in something approximating closed form?
$$
\text{E}_q[\log\Gamma(\alpha)] = \int_0^{\infty}\log\Gamma(\alpha)\frac{1}{\alpha\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\lbrace-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\left(\log(\alpha) - \mu\right)^2\right\rbrace \text{d}\alpha
$$
I tried Stirling's approximation of $\log\Gamma(x)$, which I was surprised to find gets worse as more terms are added.  unfortunately, the quality of the approximation breaks down for $x < 1$, becoming absolutely terrible near 0.

Is there some reason why numerical integration isn't considered (after, of course, setting values for $\mu$ and $\sigma$) ?

because i have to take the derivative of the quantity with respect to $\mu$ and $\sigma$, as those are the values i'm optimizing for.

Not all optimization routines require derivatives.

If I accept a numeric solution, then it's relatively simple to get a gradient around the current value.  The problem is, that doesn't allow me to find the optimum in 1 step; that would require iterating through the normal hill-climbing routines.   I want to skip that.
This is one part of a much larger inference problem, where everything else is being updated through gibbs sampling.  I am currently updating this step through MCMC, but If possible, I would rather do variational approximation using the log-normal than MCMC, as it would be faster to reach convergence.
